# Import SAS data file into R

Tags: r

I want to read in a SAS data file (sas7bdat format) into R. I've tried using sas7bdat package, but ended up getting error.

**CODE:**

```
x <- read.sas7bdat("C:\Users\petas\Desktop\airline.sas7bdat")
```

**ERROR:**

> '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `library(haven);read_sas("C:....")`

Answer (score 2):

Posting example by using `haven` library

```
install.packages("haven")
library(haven)

url <- "C:\\Users\\petas\\Desktop\\airline.sas7bdat"

x <- read_sas(url)
```

> If you use windows than you need to use instead `"\"` use `"\\"` or Unix/linux style `"/"`. Easiest will be to use `forward slashes` so will be compatible in the future with the path of any OS, in your case **Error:** `'\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"` is due the use of **single backslashes** instead **double backslashes**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using forward slashes:

```
x <- read.sas7bdat("C:/Users/petas/Desktop/airline.sas7bdat")
```